# C# handling result sets from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, networking

I have large wait times in ASYNC_NETWORK_IO on my SQL Server and I found this interesting article

http://blogs.msdn.com/joesack/archive/2009/01/09/troubleshooting-async-network-io-networkio.aspx

the part i find interesting is:

- Identify large result sets and verify with the application team (or developers) how this is being consumed. Red flags include the application querying large results sets but not processing more than a few rows at a time

If you are receiving a result set back from a linq query then you have processed it(?)
How would you process it a few rows at a time(?) is this meaning an sql reader?

How would you go about finding if the application is causing the 
ASYNC_NETWORK_IO problem?

curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many developers tend to query large results from LINQ to SQL and then trim them down instead of relying on a pattern that leverages IQueryable which means you are building a more refined query instead of refined data subset.

You may be seeing this happening: they need only a subset but they are coding to pull everything, then they filter the data out to what they actually need.

The repository pattern with IQueryable will ensure the most optimized use of SQL Server server by allowing the developer to query a large resultset and trim it down at many levels until it's actually needed.  By that time the query isn't:

1. Get all
2. Get data
3. Filter subset
4. Get data
5. Filter another subset
6. Get data
7. Display

It's:

1. From all apply a filter and then another filter
2. Get data
3. Display

Just my thoughts.

Comment: Just a note...they don't have be using linq, for this sceneario to occur. They could be pulling down whole tables just to loop through and find what they need programmtically rather than let the DB do the heavy lifting (improperly projecting).

Comment: So this is for instance, select * from big_table
Then implement a reader over it and filter with a reader or filter over a foreach instead of using a simple where filterparm=1

Comment: Yes. Instead of getting everything and then filtering it they should parameterize it and filter it out first before the data is sent from the database server to the client/web server.